# How to install working MinGW in my 32-bit Windows 10

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw

I'm a complete newbie to programming and I want to start learning C. I downloaded Visual studio code and MinGW, then tried to execute a simple 'hello world'. However, I get this error:

This version of C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running.

After some searching, I think I have figured out that it is because I'm using Windows 10 32-bit. I can't find helpful videos or tutorials. What should I do?

Comment: probably you downloaded a 64-bit build of mingw. Try downloading a 32-bit build of mingw-w64  (do not confuse the source with the target)

Answer (score 1):

Try with MinGW-w64 (e.g. from https://winlibs.com/) instead of old MinGW, and make sure VSCode is properly configured for it (see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).